# How to load test/stress test a video streaming application for mobile?

Tags: load-testing, tools, mobile, stress-testing

We have a requirement to test an interactive broadcast solution that would allow viewers to engage with a presenter through real time video and voice communication, the same will also be broadcast to a larger audience(100 users).The solution will be implemented using OPENTOK API (WEBRTC video streaming) and will be available on Mobile only

Is there a load/Stress/Performance testing tool that can handle this requirement and basically allow me to generate these 100 virtual users that can stream the interactive broadcast?

Answer (score 1):

NeoLoad can test streaming video and audio performance by detecting the media requests of an application, by simulating client/media players and providing specific statistics related to the quality of video and audio playback.

https://www.neotys.com/solutions/streaming-video-load-testing

Comment: Hi Patrick, I believe neoload does not support WebRTC Streaming. Is there a workaround for this? http://answers.neotys.com/questions/1668879-record-load-test-webrtc-video-streaming-using-neoload#answer_3766894

Comment: Not that i know of

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [How we test WebRTC live video sessions for massive audiences](https://tokbox.com/blog/test-webrtc-sessions-massive-audiences/) article I can see 2 things:

1. [TokBox](https://tokbox.com/) seems to be carefully load-testing their Cloud API so if your service relies on TokBox Cloud - you should be good to go (or focus your load testing on your application backend)
2. If you still want to perform the load test you can go for their approach and use one of [SDKs](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/java/) in order to create sessions using your favourite programming language and load testing tool. If you don't have any idea regarding which tool to choose you can check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for an overview of the most popular and advanced free and open source load testing tools and frameworks.